# VIM inefficient when working with many files

Tags: vim, plugins

When you are working with more than 20 files, the number of tabs open overflow the capacity of the tab bars and it becomes really annoying to switch between them. Also, clicking on the tabs is anti-vimish. It's really inefficient.

I've been thinking something in the lines of:
1. Tabs are kept on left (side tabs have higher capacity)
2. Letter tags are assigned to them (a, b, c, d...)
3. In order to switch to a tab you just type a key + it's tag

I think it can't get faster than this. Is there something like that?

Comment: I use buffers, there are many nice plugins, which help me to locate a file quickly. e.g. CtrlP, FuzzyFinder ... I just cannot master how to work with tabs. It always makes me confused.  maybe it is time for you to try buffers?  btw, if you say "clicking", it is anyway inefficient, since your hand/finger left home keys. :)

Comment: @Kent Yea, it is horrible. I can't get buffers, though. You have to type an insane amount of words to work with them. :ls<cr> to SEE them, then scam with your eyes (a not so friendly display), then :buN<cr> and only them you're on the file you want!

Comment: Don't make it hard. `:b` can take a partial filename and wildcards with `*`. Learn splits with `:sp`, `:vps`, `:sb`, and others. Use `<c-6>` to quickly get back to the last buffer. Use uppercase marks to return to set "bookmarks" to places you know you will return to later. If you still want to use tabs at the very least use `gt` and `gT` to switch tabs.

Comment: @PeterRincker okay I'm "getting" it. But how do I open a file over an opened buffer? Knowing how to make splits is not of much use when `:h` opens in a new window itself. (Also you meant :vsp)

Comment: @Dokkat thank you. I did mean `:vsp`. To open a buffer in place just use `:b`. If you want a new file use `:e`. I would also recommend you learn some window commands: `:h CTRL-w`. It may also be helpful to `:set hidden` which will allow you to have switch from unsaved buffers.

Answer (score 2):

In other editors, a tab is a proxy for a file: a file is opened, its content is put in memory, processed and finally displayed in a window attached to a tab with the label set to the file name. `tab == file`.

In Vim, a tab is a "workspace" designed to host any number of windows (1 by default) which can in turn display any buffer from the buffer list. Consider as well that the label of the tab is by default the name of the active window which may or may not be useful (who wants a tab labelled `Quickfix window`?). `tab != file`.

The basic unit is the buffer and buffers are *global*: a buffer can be displayed in `x` windows in `y` tabs with `x` and `y` superior or equal to `0`. Since there is *no* way to tie a buffer to a specific window or tab, using Vim tabs as if it was the case is a mistake.

The *right* way to go is drop tabs and deal with buffers, directly. After all, you want to jump to a specific file, don't you?

Navigating between buffers is both quick and easy:

```
:bn
:bp
:b <Tab>
:b *foo<Tab>
```

specially with custom mappings:

```
nnoremap gb :buffers<CR>:b<Space> " beautiful!
```

and a lot more natural than forcing Vim into that horrible tab-centric paradigm. If you still have speed concerns, even with that `gb` mapping, try CtrlP, Command-T, FuzzyFinder, LustyExplorer or their many siblings.

Also, more generally, tabs are a poor idea because they tend to loose their usefulness as their number grows… the horizontal space available for displaying tabs is generally fixed or at the very least limited. Because labels are written horizontally and file names are generally more than a couple of characters long, the available space shrinks rapidly and all kinds of compromises must be made to keep tabs "usable". Names and tabs are shortened or gyzmos are added at each end of the tab line for scrolling… basically the amount of effort needed to find what you are looking increases too rapidly for tabs to be a valid universal solution.

Answer (score 2):

I repost that [excellent blog post](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/buffers-windows-tabs/) explaining the difference between a 'window', a 'buffer' and a 'tab' in Vim.

The short version is in romainl's answer. The default way to deal with multiple files is to use buffers, tabs are only there to keep specific window layouts.

Answer (score 1):

With browsers and other applications, you have to use tabs; there's nothing else. In Vim, tab pages are only a recent (version 7) addition, and fully optional. Using too many of them is regarded as an anti-pattern by many. I typically use them to segregate different projects.

It looks like you just haven't yet found an optimal strategy for managing files inside Vim. Since this depends a lot on your project(s) and workflow, it's hard to give recommendations. But you'll find (too) many blog posts about this topic, and a plethora of plugins on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/). Be patient, try out different approaches, and you'll find a better way.

PS: What you imagine as the solution (side tabs), cannot be current done in Vim.

Comment: I've found my optimal solution, except it doesn't exist: http://o7.no/12QUcHu if the NERDTree on the left could have tags such as "aa", "ab" ,"ac"... and if I could jump to a file with "baa", for example... it would be perfect. Instead I have to use a combination of NERDTree and CTRLP and type several characters more (and also scan CtrlP results interactively, which is very lengthly). Not sure how hard it would be to implement the tag stuff. I gotta try

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`gt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#gt) to move to the next tab and `gT` to move to the previous tab.

You can also use `<number>gt` to move to the tab with that number. This allows you to move to any tab based off of its number. Tabs start counting number 1. To find out what number each tab is you can use [`:tabs`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#%3atabs)